# Loop over multiple subdirectories and download new files using SFTP

Tags: ssh, files, find, remote, sftp

I am very new to sftp but here is what I'd like to achieve:

In a remote folder `main` I have three subdirectories: `sub1`, `sub2` `sub3`. My local machine also has a `main` folder with the three subdirectories. I would like to loop over the three subdirectories, find newly created files, and place them in the corresponding local subdirectories.

It's ok if I just need to call the same command three times, one per directory, if there's no way to create a loop.

When I say I'd like to only get the new files, I'd ideally want to compare the creation/modification date of the files in my remote directory to the local equivalents (if they exist). For example, for a new file `file1.csv` in `sub1` on my remote machine, I'd like to see if there is a `file1.csv` in `sub1` on my local machine. If so, compare the dates, and if the remote one is more recent, send it to my local folder. If the file doesn't exist, directly send it to the local folder.

If this cannot be achieved, I could settle for a system that only sends files created "today" to my local folder.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "What's the best way to accomplish this?" Do it manually or automate it

Comment: https://www.golinuxcloud.com/automate-sftp-shell-script-with-password-unix/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading this right you need to get the new or changed files from the remote dirs to the local dirs.

Not sure if there is a reason you specifically want or need to use sftp ?

If you are open to alternatives, have you considered rsync ?

Plenty of online tutorials and documentation for rsync.